# How to change just one color of jpg

Tags: html, css

How can I change the white color to the red, but only white should be changed, the rest should be what they are.

Using only CSS

[image]

Comment: First, what have you tried? And second, your image doesn't appear to have white in it. Unless you possibly mean the background.

Comment: Painting the white area in red in photoshop is a 10 seconds solution to this. Not CSS.

Answer (score 2):

**CSS can't be used to dynamically edit certain pixels of an image,** as far as I know.

Alternative solutions:

1. You could overlay another element over top of the image with a partially transparent red background to sort of "paint" the image red, but this wouldn't achieve exactly what you're asking for.
2. You could have another image to switch it to that has the red background. You'd switch the image likely by doing something like `background-image: url(https://new_image_here)`
3. You can use JavaScript or similar to modify the image or provide a fancier solution...

Comment: To be fair, you can change the appearence of an image with CSS using the `mix-blend-mode` property (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) but that does not work for that case